# texstudio in line text reference error

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, bibliographystyle

```
\begin{thebibliography}{999}
    % Reference 1
    \bibitem {ref-73}   Huang, G.; Liu, Z.; Van Der Maaten, L.; Weinberger, K.Q.     Densely connected convolutional networks.   In Proceedings of the IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition 2017, Honolulu, HI, USA, 21--26 July 2017; pp 4700--4708.
```

when cite this reference in text

```
caption. Similarly,\cite{ref-73} used the
```

it shows as ,

[image]

I'm expecting

```
Similarly,[73] used the
```

how can I do that,

latex code

```
\documentclass[twoside]

\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{cases}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} 
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{soul,color}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\normalem
\setcounter{blankpages}{0}
\include{abstracts/abstract}

\tableofcontents

\let\origaddvspace\addvspace
\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{}
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

\listoftables
\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{\origaddvspace{#1}}

\include{chapters/Chapter1} 
\include{chapters/Chapter2}
\include{chapters/Chapter3}
\include{chapters/Chapter4}    
\include{chapters/Chapter5}
\include{chapters/Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The style of the cross reference is defined by the document class, so if you don't tell us what that is, nobody can help you.  Please provide a small, compilable example starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that demonstrates the problem, and that will give something to work with.

Comment: full code added to the question.

Comment: There's still no `\documentclass`, and the call to the reference is in one of the `\include`d files, so not enough information to make any intelligent guesses.

Comment: `\documentclass[twoside]` will stop with an error, so we can not run your example you  also need to remove all the `\include` that reference files we do not have